# An upper-bound problem of sum of positive numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, power-series

I came across the following problem of inequality.

If $ \ \ \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^3\leq S$

then find the value of $K$ such that

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\leq K$.

It is given that $x_i>0,\forall i\in \{1,2,3,..,n\}$

I guess it can be solved using Jensen's theorem but I can't think of the function I have to use. I think $K$ should be as a function of $n$ and $S$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use power-mean inequality.
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{a_{1}^{3}+a_{2}^{3}+\cdots +a_{n}^{3}}{n}}\ge \frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots +a_{n}}{n}$$